# pass a value from javascript to html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" name="smname" />
```

Now i have a function in a js file count(); How can I assign the return value to the hidden field?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could give your hidden field an unique id:

```
<input type="hidden" name="smname" id="smname" />
```

and then in javascript:

```
document.getElementById('smname').value = count();
```

where count is the function you want to invoke and which returns the value:

```
var count = function() {
    return 'some value';    
};
```

Comment: Or with JQuery:

$("#smname").val( count );

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
document.getElementsByName('smname')[0].value = count();
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use code such as

document.getElementById("name")

then deal with it as an object. remember to define a name/id for your html element.

Answer (score 0):

If you give the input element an `id` attribute you will be able to get a reference to it in javascript using the `document.getElementById()` method then set the `value` property of the element

*HTML*

```
<input id="surname" type="hidden" name="smname" />
```

*Javascript*

```
var input = document.getElementById("surname");
input.value = count();
```